# How can I create a simple list with small delete buttons next to them in Blazor?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erbr1.png)

It should look something like this. A simple list with a button next to each listitem to delete it. The best solution would be a html/bootstrap version but a component from a package would also be fine (only if it's free for commercial use)

I tried some lists and listgroups with `<ul>` and `<li>` but I didn't get my desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below:

```
@for(int i=0; i< Items.Count(); i++)
{
    int b = i;
    <div class="row w-25">
        <div class="col"><p>@Items[i]</p></div>
        <div class="col"><input type="button"  value="X" @onclick="() => Delete(b)"/></div>
    </div>
}

<input type="text" @bind-value=@AddText><div class="col"><input type="button"  value="Add" @onclick="args => Add()"/></div>

@code {

    List<string> Items = new List<string>{"A", "B", "C"};
    string AddText = "";

    void Delete(int indx)
    {
        Items.RemoveAt(indx);
    }

    void Add()
    {
        Items.Add(AddText);
    }

}
```

https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/GQvGlMFt01SgxwXD07

Answer (score 0):

The other answers solve the initial problem.  But I don't see a list of strings, I see a list of types of art.

Representing data, such as types of art, as a string is called **Primitive Obsession**.  Is `Artwork` the same type of art as `artwork`?  How many `Artwork` types can you have in your list?

```cs
    public List<string> Art = new() {"Artwork", "ArtWork", "Artwork"};
```

Step one is to define an `ArtType` object.

```cs
public class ArtType
{
    // there's probably an id field here to
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Udefined Type of Art";
}
```

You can then define your list of art and the appropriate methods to add and remove items from the list. Note that in any structured application the data and it's management would live in a ViewService, and not in the component.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<ol class="list-group list-group-numbered">
    @foreach (var art in Items)
    {
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-start">
            <div class="ms-2 me-auto">
                @art.Name
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" @onclick="() => Delete(art)">Delete</button>
        </li>
    }
</ol>

<div class="input-group mb-3 mt-3">
    <input class="form-control" @bind=newName />
    <button class="btn btn-success" @onclick=AddArt>Add</button>
</div>


@code {
    private string? newName;

    private List<ArtType> Items = new List<ArtType> {
        new ArtType { Name = "Painting" },
        new ArtType { Name = "Ceramics" },
        new ArtType { Name = "Abstract" }
    };

    void Delete(ArtType value)
        => Items.Remove(value);

    void AddArt(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (newName is not null)
        {
            Items.Add(new ArtType { Name = newName });
            newName = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Overengineered comes to mind ;)

Answer (score -1):

In Blazor you should be able to do something like this

```
@foreach (var item in items)
{
  <ListItem Text="@item" OnDelete="@DeleteItem" />
}

@code {
  private List<string> items = new List<string> { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3" };

  private void DeleteItem(string item)
  {
    items.Remove(item);
  }
}
```